# Windows Service gives String was not recognized as a valid DateTime exception but the same code running properly in Console Application

Tags: c#, datetime

Windows Service gives String was not recognized as a valid DateTime exception but the same code running properly in Console Application

```
Object max = cmd.ExecuteScalar();   //max will have 6/30/2012 12:00:00 AM 
DateTime currentDt = DateTime.Now;
currentDt = DateTime.ParseExact(max.ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);                         //This Line Gives Error in WindowsService Only
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("E:\\ram\\SampleService.txt", true);
sw.WriteLine(currentDt.ToString());
sw.Close();
```

I even Changed System DateTime Format Settings to Engish - Us Settings.ShortDatetime is M/d/yyyy and Longtime is h:mm:ss tt.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the *system* locale isn't the same as your *user* locale. If your system locale uses something other than "/" as the date separator, it will fail to match the "/" in your format string.

I suggest you change to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, at which point it should work - *if* the value of `max.ToString()` is actually "6/30/2012 12:00:00 AM". Have you validated that in the case it's failing, that's the value you're getting?

If your value is coming from a database though, why is it stored as a string to start with? Are you sure it even *is* a string? If it's actually a `DateTime`, then when you call `ToString()` you'll be using the current culture's default format to convert it - which could easily fail on the way back. Even if it *is* a string at the moment, does it really have to be? The fewer string conversions you can introduce, the better.

(As an aside, it's simpler to use `File.WriteAllText` or `File.AppendAllText` than using a `StreamWriter` like this. If you *do* need to use a `StreamWriter`, remember to use a `using` statement to dispose of the resource properly.)

Comment: @user1841000: Did you see my other point about the string though? Have you logged the value of `max` before trying to parse it? I *strongly* suspect you'll find you're getting a different value in the failing case.

Comment: @user1841000: Well what is the type of `max`? It sounds like it's probably a `DateTime` already - in which case you should just cast to `DateTime` instead of going via a string. It's the double string conversion which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the CultureInfo:

```
currentDt = DateTime.ParseExact(max.ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Comment: If you pass `null` as provider argument, it will use the current culture, which will effectively be the same as the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQL request return `DateTime` or `String` value?

Also I don't see why do you use `ParseExact` in this case. In your case I would suggest to use Parse method with `InvariantCulture` parameter:

```
currentDt = DateTime.Parse(max.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your `max` value is DateTime then you don't need to do parsing at all. You just need to check if it is DBNull.Value:

```
if (max != DBNullValue)
{
    currentDt = (DateTime)max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem when i had been building windows service.In that, i tryed to convert string date to datetime format. For that i used format **string date_time = Day + "/" + Mn + "/" + Yr + " " + Hr + ":" + Min;** and tryed convert it to datetime().
This format was running properly in windows form application but not in Windows service project.

Solution :

I changed above string format with this format **string date_time = Mn + "/" + Day + "/" + Yr + " " + Hr + ":" + Min;**, And then passed it to datetime().
Like follow :

> string date_time = Mn + "/" + Day + "/" + Yr + " " + Hr + ":" + Min;
>   DateTime dt_1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date_time);

By default the en-US culture is used by .NET according to which the Date is in Month/Day/Year format

This is 100% working.